# Images won't load in Rails 4 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm hoping there's a simple answer to this.

I'm using rails 4rc1 and and just building a little simple app to get myself familiar with 4.0. I tried adding an image to my view with this:
`<%= link_to image_tag('rails.png', alt: "Ruby on Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org' %>`

The path to the image i'm using is `app/assets/images/rails.png` and the `image_tag` line above points to the public directory (output is is `src="images/rails.png"`. I'm not in a production env, just in development.

Can someone please help explain what's going on here?

Thnx!

Comment: It looks like it's something to do with POW. The image loads fine under WEBrick. Any takers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also having the same problem. I just restarted the rails server and it worked for me.

Comment: If you created the "images" directory after the server was started ad you're using pow.cx, it needs a restart to work properly.